# What happens if you don't resolve or reject a promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a scenario where I am returning a promise.
The promise is basically triggered by an ajax request.

On rejecting the promise it shows an error dialog that there is a server error.

What I want to do is when the response code is 401, I neither want to resolve the promise nor reject it (because it already shows the error dialog). I want to simply redirect to the login page.

My code looks something like this:

```
function makeRequest(ur, params) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fetch(url, params).then((response) => {
      let status = response.status;    
      if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
        response.json().then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        });
      } else {
        if (status === 401) {
          redirectToLoginPage();
        } else {
          response.json().then((error) => {
            if (!error.message) {
              error.message = constants.SERVER_ERROR;
            }
            reject({ status, error });
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

As you can see, if the status is 401, I am redirecting to the login page. The promise is neither resolved nor rejected.

Is this code OK, or is there any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

A promise is just an object with properties in Javascript.  There's no magic to it.  So failing to resolve or reject a promise just fails to ever change the state from "pending" to anything else.  This doesn't cause any fundamental problem in Javascript because a promise is just a regular Javascript object.  The promise will still get garbage collected (even if still pending) if no code keeps a reference to the promise.

The real consequence here is what does that mean to the consumer of the promise if its state is never changed?  Any `.then()` or `.catch()` listeners for resolve or reject transitions will never get called.   Most code that uses promises expects them to resolve or reject at some point in the future (that's why promises are used in the first place).  If they don't, then that code generally never gets to finish its work.

Or if code is using `await` on the promise instead of `.then()`, then that function will just remain suspended forever on that `await`.  The rest of the function will be dead code and will never execute.

It's possible that you could have some other code that finishes the work for that task and the promise is just abandoned without ever doing its thing.  There's no internal problem in Javascript if you do it that way, but it is not how promises were designed to work and is generally not how the consumer of promises expect them to work.

> As you can see if the status is 401, I am redirecting to login page.
> Promise is neither resolved nor rejected.
>
> Is this code OK? Or is there any better way to accomplish this.

In this particular case, it's all OK and a redirect is a somewhat special and unique case.  A redirect to a new browser page will completely clear the current page state (including all Javascript state) so it's perfectly fine to take a shortcut with the redirect and just leave other things unresolved.  The system will completely reinitialize your Javascript state when the new page starts to load so any promises that were still pending will get cleaned up.

Comment: As you mentioned, A redirect to a new browser page will completely clear the current page state (including all Javascript state). But what will happen if I am redirecting in a single page app. I am using ReactJS. So there will be no new browser page, just a different view. Whether it's perfectly fine to take a shortcut in that case with the redirect and just leave other things unresolved.

Comment: @Aniket - Then that's a different case which your question does not describe.  You will have to make sure things are cleaned up properly so you don't have any memory leaks.  I have no idea whether there would be an issue with this in react or not.  Next time please put this type of information in your question.

Comment: Make sure you don't have references to the `reject` and `resolve` functions, and not just stop referencing the promise. Then, GC should step in. Otherwise, if your code still references `resolve` for example, then the Promise will have to stick around in case your code ever calls `resolve()`. Here's an example of a Web API that can leak Promises if not careful: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/674

Comment: For your single-page-app scenario when handling 401 you could just "return" as mentioned by @CodingIntrigue below. Sure you'll need the if(typeof json === "undefined") check but the callers of makeRequest should be checking if they have good data anyways. Callers should never blindly trust that they have good data.  For a 401 I wouldn't reject the promise. A rejected promise to me means an error should be logged... this isn't really an error but rather a simple redirect.

Comment: It is worth noting that if you're running node and you have dangling promises out there, they can prevent your node process from exiting even if it ought to be done, at least until the promise gets GC'd (which it probably won't because no new memory is being allocated if it's basically done!)

Comment: @portalguy15837 - Actually, I don't think a promise by itself prevents nodejs from exiting.  But, an asynchronous operation that is still pending that may be hooked to the promise can/will stop nodejs from exiting such as a pending network operation, a connected socket, a pending file operation, etc...  But the exiting issue is not caused by the promise.  It's caused by the pending asynchronous operation itself.

Comment: Another downside I see with this general approach is that the `finally` block will never be executed, which consumers may rely on for important cleanup logic (e.g. remove handlers, etc). I can't think of a case where a reject wouldn't be better than never resolving.

Answer (score 6):

I think the "what happens if we don't resolve reject" has been answered fine - it's your choice whether to add a `.then` or a `.catch`.

However, *Is this code OK? Or is there any better way to accomplish this*. I would say there are two things:

You are wrapping a Promise in `new Promise` when it is not necessary and the `fetch` call **can fail**, you should act on that so that your calling method doesn't sit and wait for a Promise which will never be resolved.

Here's an example (I think this should work for your business logic, not 100% sure):

```
const constants = {
  SERVER_ERROR: "500 Server Error"
};
function makeRequest(url,params) {
  // fetch already returns a Promise itself
  return fetch(url,params)
        .then((response) => {

            let status = response.status;

            // If status is forbidden, redirect to Login & return nothing,
            // indicating the end of the Promise chain
            if(status === 401) {
              redirectToLoginPage();
              return;
            }
            // If status is success, return a JSON Promise
            if(status >= 200 && status < 300) {
              return response.json();
            }
            // If status is a failure, get the JSON Promise,
            // map the message & status, then Reject the promise
            return response.json()
              .then(json => {
                if (!json.message) {
                    json.message = constants.SERVER_ERROR;
                }
                return Promise.reject({status, error: json.message});
              })
        });
}
// This can now be used as:
makeRequest("http://example", {})
  .then(json => {
    if(typeof json === "undefined") {
      // Redirect request occurred
    }
    console.log("Success:", json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error:", error.status, error.message);
  })
```

By contrast, calling your code using:

```
makeRequest("http://example", {})
  .then(info => console.log("info", info))
  .catch(err => console.log("error", err));
```

Will not log anything because the call to `http://example` will fail, but the `catch` handler will never execute.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid   
    if(typeof json === "undefined") {
          // Redirect request occurred
    }
The reason being makeRequest is called by many other functions and I have to make that check in every function that calls it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your code examples.  So for both examples the  makeRequest(..).catch won't be called?  is that right?  That is the way it reads to me.  Seem like you need a catch in your original fetch call and have it return a rejected promise.

Answer (score 3):

As others stated it's true that it's not really an issue if you don't resolve/reject a promise. Anyway I would solve your problem a bit different:

```
function makeRequest(ur,params) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {

        fetch(url,params)
        .then((response) => {

            let status = response.status;

            if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                response.json().then((data) => {
                    resolve(data);
                })
            }
            else {
                reject(response);
            }
        })
    });
}

makeRequest().then(function success(data) {
   //...
}, function error(response) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
        redirectToLoginPage();
    }
    else {
        response.json().then((error) => {
            if (!error.message) {
                error.message = constants.SERVER_ERROR;
            }

            //do sth. with error
        });
    } 
});
```

That means I would reject every bad response state and then handle this in your `error handler` of your `makeRequest`.

Comment: Does you fetch call need a .catch handler that returns a rejected promise?

Answer (score 1):

It works and isn't really a problem, except when a caller of `makeRequest` expects of promise to fulfil. So, you're breaking the contract there.

Instead, you could defer the promise, or (in this case) reject with status code/error.

Answer (score 1):

The ECMAScript spec explains the purpose of promises and `new Promise()`:

> A Promise is an object that is used as a placeholder for the eventual results of a deferred (and possibly asynchronous) computation.
>
> **25.6.3.1 Promise ( *executor* )**
>
> NOTE The *executor* argument must be a function object. It is called for initiating and reporting completion of the possibly deferred action represented by this Promise object.

You should use promises to obtain future values.  Furthermore, to keep your code concise and direct, you should *only* use promises to obtain future values, and not to do other things.

Since you’ve also mixed program control flow (redirection logic) into your promise’s “executor” logic, your promise is no longer “a placeholder for the results of a computation;” rather, it’s now a little JavaScript program masquerading as a promise.

So, instead of wrapping this JavaScript program inside a `new Promise()`, I recommend just writing it like a normal JavaScript program:

```js
async function makeRequest(url, params) {
  let response = await fetch(url, params);
  let { status } = response;
  if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
    let data = await response.json();
    successLogic(data);
  } else if (status === 401) {
    redirectToLoginPage();
  } else {
    let error = await response.json()
    if (!error.message) {
      error.message = constants.SERVER_ERROR;
    }
    errorLogic({ status, error });
  }
}
```