# Load Script Tag in Angular 2 App When Src Attribute is from Web API Call

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-web-api

**Context:**
I have an Angular 2+ application that makes calls to a web API containing URLs for a src attribute on a script tag that is created by a `loadScript` function in the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

The web API returns a JsonResult and is yielding the data I expect. I was able to interpolate some of the data in the component's template.

Additionally, before I added the call to the web API, the `loadScript` function was working with a hard-coded argument.

Reading a [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903) on github. A "member" stated that scripts are not supposed to be loaded on demand. So what I implemented with the `loadScript` function is essentially a work around, but how else would load them? I don't want to have a seemingly endless amount of script tags sitting in the index.html file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-agriculture-roadmap',
    templateUrl: './agriculture-roadmap.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./agriculture-roadmap.component.css']
})

export class RoadmapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private _httpService: Http, private _route: ActivatedRoute)
    {

    }

    apiRoadmaps: { roadmapName: string, pdfRoadmapURL: string, jsRoadmapURL: string };

    ngOnInit() {   
        this._httpService
            .get('/api/roadmaps/' + this._route.params)
            .subscribe(values => {
                this.apiRoadmaps = values.json() as { roadmapName: string, pdfRoadmapURL: string, jsRoadmapURL: string };
            });
    }

    async ngAfterViewInit() {
        await this.loadScript(this.apiRoadmaps.jsRoadmapURL);
    }

    private loadScript(scriptUrl: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const scriptElement = document.createElement('script')
            scriptElement.src = scriptUrl
            scriptElement.onload = resolve
            document.body.appendChild(scriptElement)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: one side note, you didn't `resolve` your `loadScript`. You must add `resolve()` after `document.body.appendChild(scriptElement)`. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734900/what-happens-if-we-dont-resolve-or-reject-the-promise

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular cli .
Then place these scripts in

```
angular-cli.json file under scripts array

scripts:[
.....
]
```

Please refer this [link] (https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

It has a question on how to refer third party js or scripts in Angular with or without typings.

Comment: how do you reference the scripts in a component?

Comment: Updated i already had an answer to this would have redirected you there but couldn't figure out the question properly