# Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, postgresql-12

Since today, I get the following error when I try to locally connect to a postgres database (v 12) using knex.js.

```
Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
```

This happens on a project I've been working on for a year without any problems. Trying to isolate the issue, I created a new database with one table. When running the following lines of code, I get the same error:

```
const knex = require('knex');

const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/a_test',
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
  },
});

db.from('test_table')
  .select(['id'])
  .then(r => {
    console.log(r);
  });
```

I have no clue what might cause this. A couple of weeks ago everything worked fine and I didn't change anything in the meantime. I run postgres locally with [postgresapp](https://postgresapp.com/) and when I connect to the database using `psql`, everything works fine. Any ideas where I could look to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like with Node 14 newer (>8.0.3) pg driver version should be used. https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3912

Answer (score 11):

### The problem

Nodejs V14 Made some breaking changes that affected the `pg` module! Which made it exit directly at `connect() call`.

One can know by downgrading to v13! (I call it the **v14 HELL**)! Which was a solution in the past!

A fix for pg was written in `pg v8.0.3`.

### Fix for v14

If you are using `postgres`! With nodejs v14 and above ! Make sure to use the driver module `pg` at version `>=8.0.3`! And better upgrade to the latest

```sh
npm install pg@latest --save
```

If you are not using `postgres`! Try to update your DB driver! It may be the same! Also try with nodejs `V13`. To confirm it's the same problem! (**V14 HELL**)

### What did happen in v14

If like me you like to know the details and what did happen !?

With node V14! Some breaking changes happened on the api! Also many things were changed! Including Openssl version!

For postgres! And `pg` module! The problem was as described in this [comment](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2170#issuecomment-617556848) per this [thread](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2170):

> The initial readyState (a private/undocumented API that
>
> pg uses) of net.Socket seems to have changed from 'closed' to 'open'
> in Node 14.
>
> It’s hard to fix with perfect backwards compatibility, but I think I
> have a patch that’s close enough.

And as per this [PR](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2171)!

You can see the changes in [this diffing](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2171/commits/149f48232445da0fb3022044e4f1c53509040ad3)

In short as mentioned! The api for onReady changed for a `net.Socket` !
And the implemented solution was to not use onReady at all!

And as per this

> Connection now always calls connect on its stream when connect is called on it.

In the older version the connect was called only if the socket is on `closed` state! `readyState` usage is eliminated!

Check [this line](https://github.com/charmander/node-postgres/blob/149f48232445da0fb3022044e4f1c53509040ad3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L54)

You can understand!

Depending on the implementation! Many things may or not be affected by those core changes!

#### Nodejs v14 relevant change

And because i wanted to see where the change happen! Here you go

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/32272

One can check the log of changes too:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V14.md

#### Detailed Why + exit and no logging error

Also to mention the breaking changes! Made `pg` make the process exit at `connect() call`. And that's what made it exit! And logging was to be seen!
In more detail for this! Here how it happened! Sequelize have the postgres dialect implementation! Which use pg! And pg client! create a connection! The connection have a `connect` event! When it connect it emit it! And because node v14 change the behavior of a stream to starting with open! The stream connection is skipped! Because of the `readyState` check (expected as close but it became open instead!)! And the stream is taken as connected (else block)! Where it is not! And the `connect` event is emitted directly! When that happen! The client either will call `requestSsl()` or `startup()` method of the connection object! And both will call `this._stream.write`. because the stream is not connected! An error happen! This error is not catch! Then the promise in sequelize driver! Will stay unresolved! And then the event loop get empty! Nodejs by default behavior just exit!

You can see the step through lines of code:

- [Sequelize pg adapter will call pg client to create a connection and the promise](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/febc083adee2cd3e6f24b18a556acdc4c4f50f96/src/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js#L123)
- [pg client call connect on a connection object](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L108)
- [pg connection `connect()` call and emit `connect`! Thinking the stream is connected because of V14 change](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L56)
- [pg client `connect` event catched and callback run! `requestSsl()` or `startup()` will be run](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/client.js#L115)
- One of the method get run and `stream.write` will be called ([requestSsl()](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L140), [startup()](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/aafd8ac64e588e689ed08e7957bc3c91f8fe01e3/packages/pg/lib/connection.js#L164))
- Stream Error (not catched)
- [Promise](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/febc083adee2cd3e6f24b18a556acdc4c4f50f96/src/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js#L123) in sequelize postgres adapter! Still unresolved!
- event loop empty => Nodejs => Exit

#### Why nodejs exit (unresolved promises)

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22088

[Node exits without error and doesn't await promise (Event callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914025/node-exits-without-error-and-doesnt-await-promise-event-callback)

[what happens when a Promise never resolves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966890/what-happens-when-a-promise-never-resolves)

Answer (score 3):

It is a fact that this error can be caused by very many issues, today I found out a new one the hard way after scrolling up and down countless threads like this one to no avail.

when setting up the pool, there knex allows us to optionally register `afterCreate` callback, if this callback is added it is imperative that you make the call to the `done` callback that is passed as the last parameter to your registered callback or else no connection will be acquired leading to timeout.

```
.....
    pool: {
      afterCreate: (conn, done) => {
        // .... add logic here ....
        // you must call with new connection
        done(null, conn);
      },
    }
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded my `psql` using `npm install pg@latest --save` and my `knex` now is working.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: @Tyler2P I would love to and i tried doing that but I need 50 rep points to be able to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the problem was node v14. When I use v13 or earlier it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
"express": "^4.16.2",
"knex": "^0.14.2",
"objection": "^2.1.3",
"pg": "^8.0.3",

and npm install
```

i fixed my problem (end of the 4 day)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).