# Axios promise is returning error when I attempt to make it cancellable

Tags: typescript, axios, openapi

I've been running into a problem with a specific request that may take way too long to return with data, so I've been looking into making the promise "cancellable" to just ignore it after I change a filter for the request. I realize that there are now things in Axios to cancel requests, but the project I'm working on has a pretty outdated version that doesn't have that functionality. A little while ago, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58002434/18457309) and "Typescript-ified" it to this;

```js
export function makeCancellable<T, F>(fn: (param: T, options?: any) => AxiosPromise<F>) {
    let reject_: (reason?: any) => void; // cache for the latest `reject` executable
    return function(param: T, options?: any) {
        if(reject_) reject_(new Error('_cancelled_')); // If previous reject_ exists, cancel it.
                                                       // Note, this has an effect only if the previous race is still pending.
        let canceller = new Promise<AxiosResponse<F>>((_, reject) => { // create canceller promise
            reject_ = reject; // cache the canceller's `reject` executable
        });
        return Promise.race([canceller, fn(param, options)]); // now race the promise of interest against the canceller
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to make the promise cancellable, it returns `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configuration')`. OpenAPI is being used to generate these requests, and I make the request as follows;

```js
   cancellableRequest = makeCancellable(this.api.request);
```

This is in a service class, and is instantiated in the constructor(hence the no `const` or `var` ect...). Then when I call the function to start the promise, it gives me that error back.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was because I was no longer calling the function from the context it came from, so the solution was just to pass in the context of the API class it came from.

So instead of `fn(param, options)`, I had to use `fn.apply(api, [param, options])`. All that had to be done to do that was just passing in the API context to the `makeCancellable` function as any. I'm not 100% sure how it works, so this is the best explanation I can give as of right now.