# Create promise which never fulfils

Tags: javascript, promise

How can I create a promise which will never fulfil?
So that for example this will never reach `console.log`:

```
const res = await NEVER_FULLFILLING_PROMISE

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `new Promise(() => {})`, but why would you need this?

Comment: @SebastianSimon its useful for Svelte, when you use the {await} block to wait for a promise, but the promise gets set onMount and since you cannot await an undeclared variable, you just create an unfulfillable promise at the beginning and override it onMount

Comment: Related: [What happens if you don't resolve or reject a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36734900/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `new Promise` and never call the first parameter in the callback.

```js
(async () => {
  await new Promise(() => {});
  console.log('done');
})();
```

Another approach that fulfills the *text* of your question (but probably not the intent) would be to make the Promise reject, of course.

```js
(async () => {
  await new Promise((_, reject) => reject());
  console.log('done');
})()
  .catch(() => {});
```