# Check Typescript Promise exhaustively covered with resolve | reject

Tags: typescript

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734900/what-happens-if-you-dont-resolve-or-reject-a-promise), I want to *statically* check if a `Promise` is guaranteed to `resolve` or `reject`:

```
function foo(x: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (x > 30) { resolve(x+7);       }
    if (x < 20) { reject("ouch !!!"); }
  });
}

async function main() {
  try { const y = await(foo(60)); console.log(y); }
  catch (e) {                     console.log(e); }
}

main();
```

Can the approach for enums coverage (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58009992/3357352)) be extended to `number` coverage?

**EDIT**:

I guess for the very least I would like to specify the
return type of the promise so an `undefined` is *not* a
valid value. Something similar to:

```
$ cat example.ts                         
function bar(x: number): number { if (x > 30) { return x-2; }}
$ npx tsc --strict --target es2020 example.ts | grep error
example.ts(1,26): error TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
```

Comment: I suspect that may require solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) if you want it to cover all cases.

Comment: Indeed - I'm talking about handling *some* cases - like the one mentioned here? Or am I overly optimistic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use async functions

```
// ~! Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.(2366)
async function foo(x: number): Promise<number> {
    if (x > 30) { return (x + 7); }
    if (x < 20) { throw new Error("ouch !!!"); }
}
```

Promises are *especially* used in cases where *you have no idea when you return something*

Comment: Oh I see ... so a similar check is *not* done for promises because from their very nature, promises are "less explicit" than plain functions are (something like that?)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. But noone does such things for a reason. Math in typescript is very inefficient (as there is no math operations out of the box), and even such easy operators as `type Add<T extends number, K extends number>` are really complex and, even if impemented, would dramatically affect your project compilation time.

here are [example solutions](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues?q=label%3A274+label%3Aanswer+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc) how simple numbers comparison can be implemented on typescript static types system.